# Compare two version numbers in the form Major.Minor.Patch.Build to see if one is less than or greater than the other

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.7.0

```
from sys import argv
class Version:
    def __init__(self, ver_str):
        if type(ver_str) != 'string':
            ver_list = ver_str.split('.')
            self.Major = int(ver_list[0])
            self.Minor = int(ver_list[1])
            self.Patch = int(ver_list[2])
            self.Build = int(ver_list[3])

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(self.Major, self.Minor, self.Patch, self.Build)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other.Major != self.Major:
            return self.Major < other.Major
        elif other.Minor != self.Minor:
            return self.Minor < other.Minor
        elif other.Patch != self.Patch:
            return self.Patch < other.Patch

        else:
            return self.Build < other.Build 

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other.Major != self.Major:
            return self.Major > other.Major
        elif other.Minor != self.Minor:
            return self.Minor > other.Minor
        elif other.Patch != self.Patch:
            return self.Patch > other.Patch

        else:
            return self.Build > other.Build 

    def printme(self):
        print("{}.{}.{}.{}".format(self.Major, self.Minor, self.Patch, self.Build))


def main(argv):
    validate_args(argv)

    ver_1 = Version(argv[1])

    ver_2 = Version(argv[2])
    op = argv[3]

    if op == '<':
        print("{} < {}: {}".format(ver_1, ver_2, ver_1 < ver_2))
    elif op == '>':
        print("{} > {}: {}".format(ver_1, ver_2, ver_1 > ver_2))
    else:
        print("Incorrect operator")
        exit(-1)

def validate_args(argv):
    no_of_args = len(argv)
    if no_of_args != 4:
        print("USAGE: {} 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 '<' or '>'".format(argv[0]))
        exit(-1)
    if (len(argv[1].split('.')) != 4) or (len(argv[2].split('.')) != 4):
        print("USAGE: {} 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2. '<' or '>' IMPROPER VERSION FORMAT".format(argv[0]))
        exit(-1)
    if argv[3] != '>' and argv[3] != '<':
        print("USAGE: {} 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2. '<' or '>' IMPROPER OPERATOR".format(argv[0]))
        exit(-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(argv)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, have you looked at `LooseVersion` and/or `StrictVersion` from [`distutils.version`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version)?  They might already provide you with exactly what you need.

---

General “PEP-8” Comments:

You should have a blank line after your import, after `class Version`, and after the `def __repr__(self)` method.  The blank-lines inside of `__lt__` and `__gt__` functions before the `else:` clause are inconsistent.

Your class and methods could benefit from `"""doc strings"""`.

The class members `Major`, `Minor`, `Patch` and `Build` should all be lower case.  Only class names should begin with capital letters.  Since the members should be private to the class, they should also be prefixed with an underscore.

---

The constructor will silently fail if `type(ver_str) != 'string'` is ever `False`, and then the instance becomes useless, as the members which are required in every other method of the class become reference errors.  There is no need to check if `ver_str` is a string; just try to split it, and convert the parts to integers.  If you haven’t passed in a string, the split or conversion to integers will cause an exception.  (You could add a check that the split produces exactly 4 parts, to reject a version such as "1.2.3.4.5.6".)

Fortunately (as noted by @200_success in the comments), `type(ver_str)` will never equal `'string'`, because `type(...)` doesn't return strings; it returns types.  The code only works because the test inverts the condition, and reads `!=` when the intention is for the type to `==` a string.  The correct test would be closer to `if isinstance(ver_str, str):`, but again explicit type checking is an anti-pattern.

Without the explicit type checking, and using a more functional approach, the constructor could be written as a one line method.  As a side-effect of the deconstruction assignment, the version string must contain exactly 4 parts or an exception will be raised.

```
def __init__(self, ver_str):
    self.Major, self.Minor, self.Patch, self.Build = map(int, ver_str.split('.'))
```

---

`printme()` is unused and could be deleted.  If you don’t wish to delete it, at least name it using snake_case to make it more readable: `print_me()`.  You could write the function as simply `print(repr(self))` to avoid duplicating code.

---

`__repr__(self)` should actually return a string like `Version("1.2.3.4")`, not the string `"1.2.3.4"` to conform to the `repr()` contract.  What you have written would make a great `__str__(self)` method though, and you could then implement `__repr__(self)` using the `str()` method.

---

Inside `def main(...):`, you are using `argv`.  This is a different `argv`, shadowing the one you import from `sys` using `from sys import argv`.

You should avoid shadowing the imported name, by using:

```
import sys

# ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

There is no need to `exit(-1)` from `main()`, since the program will terminate anyway immediately.  `exit()` will terminate the Python interpreter, which can be unexpected, and can cause resources to not be properly closed.  A unit test framework will abruptly terminate, preventing recording of the test results, and preventing other unit tests from running.  In short, don’t ever use `exit()`.  Ever.

---

Since you are explicitly writing for Python 3.7.0, you can use f-strings.  This means you can replace many of your `.format(...)` calls with a more compact, readable representation where the substitution location and value are combined.  Ie:

```
    print("{} < {}: {}".format(ver_1, ver_2, ver_1 < ver_2))
```

could become simply:

```
    print(f"{ver_1} < {ver_2}: {ver_1 < ver_2}")
```

Comment: The `type(ver_str)` check is even more bizarre, when you consider that `type('1.2.3.4') == 'string'` if `False`. I have no idea what that check in the initializer is intended to accomplish.

Comment: @200_success Wow.  I knew the explicit type-checking was bad, but I totally missed that it was outright wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Python tuples already sort the way you want to, so you can replace your class with just a thin wrapper around the built-in `tuple` class. You only need a constructor that can parse a string of the form `"3.1.0.2"` into a tuple of ints and a nice representation as a version string:

```
class VersionTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, s):
        return super().__new__(cls, map(int, s.split(".")))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ".".join(map(str, self))
```

Note that this does not restrict the number of arguments to include a major, minor, patch and build version. If you want that, you can instead inherit from a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

class VersionTuple(namedtuple("VersionTuple", "major minor patch build")):
    def __new__(cls, s):
        return super().__new__(cls, *map(int, s.split(".")))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ".".join(map(str, self))
```

---

Both work the same way with respect to comparisons (you even get the equality operator for free):

```
VersionTuple("3.1.0.0") < VersionTuple("3.1.2.0")
# True
VersionTuple("1.0.0.0") > VersionTuple("3.1.2.0")
# False
VersionTuple("1.0.0.0") == VersionTuple("1.0.0.0")
# True
```

And printing:

```
print(VersionTuple("3.6.3.0"))
# 3.6.3.0
```

While the latter allows you to also access the individual parts:

```
VersionTuple("3.6.3.0").patch
# 3
```

It also raises a `TypeError` if the version string does not contain four parts:

```
VersionTuple("3.6.3")
# ...
# TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'build'
```